# What's the best way to return 2 (or more) variables from a method in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, multiple-return-values

What is the best way to return 2 (or more) variables from a method?

Say I want to return 2 integer values (ex. a=10 & b=20) to the (parent) method and load them to the variables myFirst and mySecond.

Both ways work, but which one is better?

1) "Classical" Way:

```
-(int *)returnMyValues1
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    static int myResult[2];

    myResult[0] = a;
    myResult[1] = b;

    return myResult;
}

...

int *result;
result = [viewSeatsAndMore returnMyValues];
myFirst = *result;
mySecond = *(result+1);
```

2) "Objective" Way:

```
-(NSArray *)returnMyValues2
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a], [NSNumber numberWithInt:b], nil];
}

...

NSArray *result = [self returnMyValues2];
myFirst = [[result objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
mySecond = [[result objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

In regard to speed, testing them with 1 million iterations, the 1st way is by 6 seconds faster.

But what about memory? Is the "static int" better than a NSArray?

Does the reservation of memory (due to the static int) not worth the (negligible) speed gain?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really-really depends on your specific use case. Do you need the method to be fast? If you don't, then just go ahead and use an `NSArray`, although I'd recommend you use the modern syntax which is more succinct, consequently easier to read:

```
- (NSArray *)returnAnArray {
    return @[ @42, @1337 ];
}
```

If you are sure you will only ever need to return two (or a small, fixed number of) integers, you can return a struct too:

```
typedef struct {
    int first;
    int second;
} TwoInts;

- (TwoInts)returnTwoInts {
    return (TwoInts){ 13, 37 };
}
```

By the way, your "classic" approach above is… dangerous and ugly. `static` variables are shared across function calls (even across method calls on different objects). This is, normally, completely different from the expected semantics of a method that returns something related to the object, so it confuses programmers trying to use your code. Don't do that.

Comment: That was exactly my point. I tried to find a "classic" way, but I was put-off by the static int that I had to use. Hence the question. I had thought of the struct way, but I thought that was "too much" for just a one off use...